# Array element values changing without reason

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, discord.js

I am trying to make a discord bot for my server (a currency bot) and I am trying to implement a trading system, but the arrays I am using for the traded items have items whose values change randomly. I haven't changed the arrays value anywhere else but the values are still changing. Does anyone know why? The code parses inputs like this: `3apple,1stick 1axe` .

`trade.ts`

```js
youend = [];
themend = [];
var temp: Item | undefined;
for (var i = 0; i < you.length; i++) {
  const item = you[i];
  for (let i = 0; i < ITEMS.length; i++) {
    const item2 = ITEMS[i];
    temp = undefined;
    if (
      reAll(
        item
          .slice(/[a-z]/i.exec(reAll(item.toLowerCase(), "_", " "))?.index)
          .toLowerCase(),
        "_",
        " "
      ) === item2.name.toLowerCase()
    ) {
      let temp = item2;
      //@ts-ignore
      temp.amount = parseInt(
        item.slice(
          0,
          /[a-z]/i.exec(reAll(item.toLowerCase(), "_", " "))?.index + 1
        )
      );
      youend.push(temp);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(temp), youend, themend);
    }
  }
}
temp = undefined;
for (var i = 0; i < them.length; i++) {
  const item = them[i];
  for (let i = 0; i < ITEMS.length; i++) {
    const item2 = ITEMS[i];
    temp = undefined;
    if (
      reAll(
        item
          .slice(/[a-z]/i.exec(reAll(item.toLowerCase(), "_", " "))?.index)
          .toLowerCase(),
        "_",
        " "
      ) === item2.name.toLowerCase()
    ) {
      let temp = item2;
      //@ts-ignore
      temp.amount = parseInt(
        item.slice(
          0,
          /[a-z]/i.exec(reAll(item.toLowerCase(), "_", " "))?.index + 1
        )
      );
      themend.push(temp);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(temp), youend, themend);
    }
  }
}
```

The item class

```js
export class Item {
    name: string
    icon: string
    sell: number
    durability: number
    amount: number
    constructor(name: string, icon: string, sell: number, durability: number, amount: number) {
        this.name = name
        this.icon = icon
        this.sell = sell
        this.durability = durability
        this.amount = amount
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok Ill run it through prettier real quick.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the index correctly? You have a double for-loop, yet you have `var i = 0` and `let i = 0`, then you access this `i`. I think this is a likely source of error. Also, this code compiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the solution, but it looks like you are using two `i` variables in the `for` loops.

---

In both of your `for` loops, you are defining two `i` variables, using `var` and `let`.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arrTwo.length; i++) {
    
  }
}
```

This shouldn't work correctly, so a good fix for it is to simply change both of them to different variable names.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; i < arrTwo.length; i++) {
    
  }
}
```

Also, you shouldn't use both `var` and `let`. You should just stick to one.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; i < arrTwo.length; i++) {
    
  }
}
```

These changes might fix your code.

---

In conclusion, the solution might be to change the variable names.

Comment: Thanks I didn't realise that I had `i` on both for loops. I don't know how I even missed that.